# Ajax jQuery Best practices: avoid inline script?? then how do I pass variables

Tags: jquery, ajax, inline-scripting

I just read in a best practices article for jquery and ajax that I should avoid defining behavior for elements on the page with inline script. That does make sense since it makes the code very readable.

However, I want to ask what should I do then, if I need to pass server-side variables to javascript. Like consider the following code...

```
<?php foreach($product as $product_id): ?>
<input type="button" value="Delete Favorite" onclick="delete_favorite('<?php echo $product_id; ?>')" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Should I be using hidden form values for such a case? or may be adding adding the server side variable in the id of element I am defining the behavior for? like so..

```
<input type="button" value="Delete Favorite" id="button<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you could do, one of them would be use a custom attribute such as `data-product-id` (`data-` prefix is in HTML5 spec I believe).

Though, you could also give that `input` an `id` such as `product-343` and then get the id using...

```
$(this)[0].id.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

(assume `this` points to an `input` element).

Comment: +1 Very thoughtful. Just the thing I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `data-` prefix attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/zJWfB/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach($product as $product_id): ?>
    <input id="fav-<?php echo $product_id; ?>" class="prod-fav" type="button" value="Delete Favorite"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".prod-fav").click(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
            var id = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
            delete_favorite(id); // Call delete_favorite or
                    //delete_favorite.call($this, id); //To retain the calling element context or
                    // implement you delete function right here..
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: This is how I often do it - just a handy note, `\D` is the same as `[^0-9]` :)

Comment: Regular expressions that are intuitive? Good luck :P +1 for doing it similar to my suggestion too :)

Comment: Well to some extent possible I guess :)